# Как сделать ввод многострочного текста (из консоли) в си?

Tags: c, массивы, строки, указатели

Мне кажется, что это можно реализовать через указатель на указатель с последующим перевыделением памяти. Но проблема в том, что кол-во символов и кол-во строк у нас не указано. Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: Читайте [man realloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего это сделать обычным односвязным списком.

```
struct Line {
  Line* Next;
  char line[MAX_SIZE];
};

Line* firstLine = NULL;
```

И вставляйте строки сколько угодно. Саму строку в структуре тоже можно сделать указателем и выделять динамически. Немного усложнится, зато память сэкономится.